# libboost_python.so linking error (ONIPY)

Tags: python, boost, wrapper, kinect, openni

I am trying to install [ONIPY](http://code.google.com/p/onipy/) on ubuntu 11.10. I am using python 2.7. After modifying (I replaced python2.6 with python2.7) the makefile and installing it I can't import the wrapper library.

ERROR:

```
>>> import OpenNIPythonWrapper

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/OpenNIPythonWrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it after trying some modifications on the makefile. So changes are as follows...

BEFORE :

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -fPIC -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(LIBS) -o $@ $^
```

AFTER:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,OpenNIPythonWrapper.so -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```